# Using Bootstrap-4 in Django 1.11

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, bootstrap-4

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello Customer</h1>

    <div class="control-group">
    {{r_form.as_p}}
    {{c_form.as_p}}
    <button class='btn btn-success' type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Base.html is equipped with all static requirements.
How to apply bootstrap to the above fields?
Have tried many ways still am not able to apply.

Comment: are you using model forms? If yes, you can apply them using `attr` attribute for form filed.

Answer (score 0):

first define static directory in settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
 )
```

second, add bootstrap files to **static/static_dirs** directory

third, change head of template like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <head>
        <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
</html>
```

now you can use defined class of bootstrap

Comment: Base.html is equipped with all static requirements.